# Fade in data when loaded swift

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview

I currently have a collectionView that loads images from a firebase database. I was curious as to how I can make these images fade in once they are loaded from the database rather than them flashing abruptly. How would I got about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When you get your image you can animate your imageView alpha, remember to set the alpha value at the beginning to 0.0

```
self.imageView.alpha = 0.0

//inside the func that get your image
UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .easeIn, animations: {
    self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
}).startAnimation()
```